# How to show that $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right] = \mathbf{A}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]$

Tags: probability

If $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n, m}$ is some random matrix, how do I show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right] = \mathbf{A}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is of suitable dimension?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the statement when $n = m =1$?

Answer (score 2):

This follows immediately from the definition (performing the matrix multiplication and employing linearity of the expectation). Let $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n} $ and
$\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{d, m}$
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}]
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[ \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{m} a_{i, k}x_{k, j}\right]_{ \substack{1 \leqslant i \leqslant d\\[2pt]
1\leqslant j\leqslant n}}\right]
\\[5pt] 
&= 
\left[\mathbb{E}\!\left[  \sum_{k = 1}^{m} a_{i, k}x_{k, j}\right] \right]_{ \substack{1 \leqslant i \leqslant d\\[2pt]
1\leqslant j\leqslant n}}
\\[5pt] 
&= 
\left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{m} a_{i, k}\mathbb{E}[ x_{k, j}] \right]_{ \substack{1 \leqslant i \leqslant d\\[2pt]
1\leqslant j\leqslant n}}
= \mathbf{A}\mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{X}]
.\end{align*}
$$
As stated in the comment, you mimic the computation of the case where $m=n=1$ and apply it to each component of the matrix resulting from the matrix product.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: @geetha290krm I see, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer to your question is about notation. If $\mathbf{Y}$ is a matrix $n\times m$ such that $\mathbf{Y}=[Y_{ij}]$, with $Y_{ij}$ being a r.v. in the position $i,j$, $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{Y})=[\mathbb{E}(Y_{ij})], i=1,\ldots,n,\ \ j=1,\ldots,m$$.

Therefore, for $\mathbf{A}$ $n\times l$ and $\mathbf{X}$ $l\times m$ if $\mathbf{Y=AX}$, $Y_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^l A_{ik} X_{kj}$ and because of the linearity property of $\mathbb{E}$, $$\mathbb{E}(Y_{ij})=\sum_{k=1}^m \mathbb{E}(A_{ik} X_{kj})=\sum_{k=1}^m \sigma_{ik,kj}+\mathbb{E}(A_{ik}) \mathbb{E}(X_{kj}), i=1,\ldots,n,\ \ j=1,\ldots,m.$$

In this last expression $\sigma_{ik,kj}=\text{cov}(A_{ik},X_{kj})$. If $\sigma_{ik,kj}=0$ for all possible i,k,j, because of independence or zero covariance,
$$\mathbb{E}(Y_{ij})=\sum_{k=1}^m \mathbb{E}(A_{ik}) \mathbb{E}(X_{kj}), i=1,\ldots,n,\ \ j=1,\ldots,m. (\text{zero covariance})$$
That is $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X})\ \text{(with zero covariance or independence)}$$
If $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix of constants, this last expression is valid with $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{A}$ and, in this case, $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X})=\mathbf{A}\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X}) \ \ \ \ (\mathbf{A}\ \text{is a matrix of constants}).$$